# I'd like to submit a HTML Service Form in GoogleScript

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, submit

I have a form created in the HTML-Service of GoogleScript.
I'd like the user to input some values in this form.
After that I'd like the user to press the submit button and "work" with the user-input.

My question now is how I can get on the user-input the user put into the form in the HTMLService Pop Up Window.

I already added the  and also added a submit-button to this form.
But when I click on this nothing happens.

Here is the code of the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <script>

 function formSubmit() {
            google.script.run.Wertezeigen(document.forms[0]);
        }

  </script>


  <body>

<p>Dieses Formular erzeugt ein neues Triage Dokument und speichert es mit den eingegebenen Werten in xyz ab.</p>


<form id="Triage_Template">

<table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 460px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 110px">
<col style="width: 350px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Gebäude:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gebaude"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prozessbereich:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prozessbereich"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Straße:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="straße"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Objekt:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="objekt"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Defekt:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="defekt"></td>
  </tr>
</table><br>


  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Submit" />

</form>


  </body>
</html>
```

Function in Code.gs:

```
function Wertezeigen(form) {

  var vorname_test = form.gebaude;
  alert(vorname_test);
  }
```

What I'm trying right now is quite simple:
I want to show the input of the input-box "gebaude" in the form as an alert when the user clicks on submit.

Comment: You need to `preventDefault` action on form submit so that the default action is prevented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each form input a unique ID:

```
<input type="text" name="gebaude" id="gebaude">
```

Since you're trying to show this in your HTML page once you've clicked submit, use `return` instead of `alert`:

```
return form.gebaude;
```

Change your form submit button to the following code:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" 
        onclick="this.value='Submitting...';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(formSubmitted)
        .Wertezeigen(this.parentNode);
        return false;">
</form>
  <div id="output"></div>
```

Then include this script just before the end of your HTML code:

```
<script> 
  function formSubmitted(status) {
    document.getElementById('Triage_Template').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Ok... did this - but still nothing happens when i click the submit button... Any other ideas?

Comment: Your function is not `return`ing anything, I've added some extra information to the answer.

Comment: Tried this... but doesn't work either... Still nothing happens when i click on 'submit'
Is it correct that the HTML-Form stays open after clicking on submit? Maybe here is already a mistake?